# Bootstrap + Datepicker

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, focus

I have made a form with different inputs.
One of these allow to choose a date, made with this very nice package:
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

The only problem is that all the form fields have the default blue focus:

```
.uneditable-input:focus {
 border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
 outline: 0;
 outline: thin dotted \9;
 ...
 }
```

But the field made with Bootstrap-Datepicker has a yellow default focus, that I am not able to modify.

How can I remove that style and apply the default bootstrap style, so to obtain consistency?

Comment: I don't see the yellow color in this example: http://bootply.com/86820 Can you post your code or create a Bootply/fiddle?

Comment: Interesting that in your example it is blue.
I have created this:
http://bootply.com/86833
And also user Devo created this for a previous question:
http://jsfiddle.net/PBcFK/

And in the both there is focus orange on the field.
How did you manage to make it blue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the latest Bootstrap 3, you just need to add the `form-control` class to your inputs and it will override the datepicker's yellow outline. I also wrapped the inputs inside `col-md-3' since Bootstrap 3 no longer defines a specific width for inputs.

```
<div class="input-append date ">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Arrival Date</label>
    <input name="arrival" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="checkin" placeholder="click here"> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-append date"> 
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Outgoing Date</label>
    <input name="outgoing" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="checkout" placeholder="click here">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/86834

EDIT:

For **Bootstrap 2.x** just make sure you add `type="text"` to your inputs and it will show the blue outline. I've update the Bootply.

Comment: Sorry Skelly. I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 for this project.
I can do something similar to resolve the problem?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. Make sure you use `type=text` in the input fields.